# TS doesn't give error and is inconsistent when assigning string to empty object

Tags: typescript, object

Could anyone help me figure out what is happening in the below code:

```
// no error
const quz: {} = "abc"

// no error
const bar: {
  link?: any;
} = ""

//Type '""' has no properties in common with type '{ buz?: any; }'.
const foo: {
  buz?: any;
} = ""
```

Playground link: [click me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/PTAEDsHtQUwJzpOAoAxpcBnALqAjgK4BeAXKAN4C+oAvKAEQCGARqvcsiBNPIiullzNGcMuWQBIADYBLcAGsA-GUbgAngG5k1OvXadgAFTUAHGKADkei6AAWjTN1AnEZuNhkxHc0OgC2fhigAO4y2Lag2KbmFuSgzMTKoKqaoJQWAHRoGDigAGaQkGKSCURJKVo6DPRAA)

I would assume that all three would throw error, still only the last one does. What is the most surprising is that if you would change `link?` property to `links?` in the second example, you would get an error as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. any `String` instance is an object, just like `{}`, and it's type is `typeof String`.
2. TypeScript does what's called "duck typing". That means any two interfaces with all properties/methods matching are interchangeable.
3. `link` is a *method* on the `String` type (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link), meaning `bar`s interface is "duck typed" to be interchangeable with `typeof String`.
4. `buz` is *not* a property or method of `typeof String` so it's not "duck typed" to be interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks! This clarifies a lot. I figured that having a `object & {link?: any}` type would make it work as expected. Unfortunately, In real application those type definitions are generated for me, so I can't do that. 
Do you know of any way to 'ask' the typescript compiler to treat `{link?: any}` as a non-primitive (not a string)?

Comment: I can only think of a type guard which might work, but if you can't change the interface you'd have to use the typeguard everywhere and wouldn't be blocked from assigning strings to these variables.